# Are videos haram or halal (given that images are haram)

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sunnah

As salam!! I read in many articles that pictures, images are *haram* in Islam!! since, i ask myself a question. videos are made of images (generally 30 frames by second). are videos forbidden or not??
As salam!!

Answer (score 1):

Peace be upon you,
A majority of scholars argue that images taken by camera is permisible, because it works like mirror. Recording videos are also same. Maybe its the reason why scholars come to TV shows.
And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

A major reason why videos are -primarily- considered as halal is that they show living things as they are: one could say "life" while pictures or images just show an instant record. Note that this doesn't make all videos halal, as they may have haram content. Sheikh 'Omar 'Abdulkafi once said in a lesson i was visiting "*I prefer my lessons being recorded by videos as they show me as I'm in real life while a picture might show just a special aspect of me*".